# nodejs - locks, keys and workers - synchronous code and waiting in javascript world

Tags: javascript, synchronization, task, worker

classic problem, this time encountered in a nodejs environment and after thinking about it for a while i'm not sure what's the best way to solve this.

i have:

- 4 resources - lets call these "keys".
- X tasks - lets call these "locks".
- Y workers - between 1 to 4 actually.

A combination of 1 task and 1 resource (doesn't matter which) is a job to be done by a worker: or in other words -  worker opens the lock with the key:)

I want to open to open these locks as fast as possible using my resources and workers.
Each worker should try to grab a key, grab a lock, unlock the lock, then put his key back.
When no keys are available a worker needs to wait till one is there.
When all locks are open workers can go home and enjoy a beer.

how would you solve this in a javascript / nodejs environment?
feel free to use redis/mongo/whatever tool you need to make this happen.

Please help me set my workers early back home today! :)

Comment: Is this a homework question? Spawn your workers, give each of them a key and a callback. When they callback, give them another key...

Comment: not homework, real live problem that is so classic it sounds like homework. I solved it before with Java where you have all the tools for the job - blocking queues, wait & notify, semaphores and so on. in javascript it's a little trickier cause everything is asynchronous. I already googled for this abit but all of the answers always have to do with just one lock and 2 processes waiting for it. the situation here is more complex (but maybe solvable in the same way and I just didn't figure it out yet). If you want to answer please do so in an answer form with some more detail.

Comment: If your problem requires the tasks to interact with the same data in a write-manner at the same time then a more detailed solution might be called for -- otherwise it really is just as Oleg said. looking into http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html would help with the usual problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RabbitMQ to solve this problem. You can maintain 4 different queues for each worker. Every worker will be bind to a separate queue.

> So the worker will be waiting till there is no message on the queue.
>   As soon as there is a message in your case a key the worker will start
>   processing complete the task and again wait for the next key.

There will be single publisher and multiple listeners i.e. single supervisor and multiple workers.
You can even implement a batch processing if required.

for example:

```
  connection.on('ready', function () {
    connection.queue("queue_name", function(queue){
        connection.exchange('exchange_name', {type: 'topic', confirm: true},function(exchange){
            queue.bind('exchange_name'); 
            queue.subscribe({ack: true},function (message, headers, deliveryInfo) {
                try{
                    var data = unescape(message.data);
                    processMessage(data); // whatever needs to be done with the received message
                    queue.shift();
                }
                catch(e){
                    console.log('Some error occured.'+ e);
                }
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: I actually solved it a little differently, not using rabbitMQ, but the same basic principal applies: use something External to ensure a locking mechanism. in my case it was Kue + Redis. only needed one job queue with 4 workers listening to this job name and performing their actions. After each job was done i deleted it so I was able to tell that all jobs were done when there were no more jobs of this kind in the Kue.